# Time based on size based log rotation for rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, log-rotation

Can we implement log rotation for custom logger with both time based and size based log rotation?

Comment: why don't you use operating system's logrotate for that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply We will check  for logrotate